set timeout -1 is endless and not executing
I have an expect script that helps me during installation of a certain file. The installation process includes a couple of [yes/no] questions and then the actual installation begins.
The [yes/no] questions hardly take time to load whereas the actual installation takes 100-120 seconds.
I want the expected statements to be answered as quickly as they can. That is why I disabled timeout using

set timeout -1

However, the send statements are taking infinite time to execute on the [yes/no] questions when I do that.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/78930604/7552

I believe that there is a log file being generated during this installation process, so in the "longest" moment, a :label in loop can help you read the last line of the file and confirm that it points to "this step completed", if not find the string,
wait for a timeout 3 | echo. [Fixed sentence with:] wait a few seconds....

If this works for you, I can share an example. Just let me know, and I’ll provide a solution. There are other options as well, but a better understanding of the commands used in your batch file would be needed to suggest the most accurate solution.
